# Display tomorrow's date in Django template

Tags: python, django, date, django-templates

I want to display tomorrow's date. I am using a generic `ListView`.

Today's date is easy via:

```
{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

Comment: did you try `tomorrow` ?

Comment: I waited a whole day and the date that I wanted yesterday as tomorrow shows up today. ;) But seriously, I actually tried this before you asked and there is no built-in for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope this solution will be also helpful. In your template tag register new template

```
import datetime
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def addDays(days):
   newDate = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
   return newDate
```

Then in template you can use it in a different way like:

- **{{ 1|addDays }}** - for tommorow
- **{{ 7|addDays }}** - for next week
- **{{ 3|addDays|date:"Y-m-d" }}** - for 3 days from now with date format "Y-m-d"
- **{{ -1|addDays }}** - for yesterday... etc.

Answer (score 6):

A custom template tag would do the trick here.

```
from django import template
from datetime import datetime

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def tomorrow(format):
    tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return tomorrow.strftime(format)
```

Remember to use the format as followed by `datetime` module in python.

Then in template

```
{% tomorrow "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" %}
```